# Basic IOS: Referencing .plist files in storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, uistoryboard, info.plist

I'm new to ios app development and am using the storyboard in xcode 5 to map out the main tab bar.   Each tab bar item is a navigation controller that has several levels.

Right now, I'm manually typing in the titles of the tab bar items into everything: the navigation controllers, corresponding view controllers, and labels.  Typing the title in apple's GUI takes a lot of time and I end up having to retype the title of a tab bar 4 or 5 times for each navigation, as well as each time I decide to change the title of a tab bar (i.e. from 'Manage Profile' to 'Profile').

I was looking up a way to create a dictionary in the Info.plist called 'TabBarItems', and have keys look like 'one'  -> 'Newsfeed' , 'two' -> 'Notifications'  ... etc.

The trouble I'm having is, I don't know how to reference the Info.plist in the storyboard file.  For example, in storyboard source code:

```
<navigationItem key="navigationItem" title= /* TabBar['two']? */ id="oV5-9c-DoH"/>
```

Or concatenation

```
<navTitle key="navigationItem" title= /* 'NavTitle' + TabBar['two'] */ id="oV5-9c-DoH"/>
```

Where TabBar['two'] gets the string, 'navigation', from Info.plist

---

This question could be extended in general, I guess, to referencing resources across groups/directories.

Comment: Describe your UI in more detail. Should you just be using a plist (not info plist) and code which uses it to create / configure your view controllers?

Comment: The UI is basically instagram, 5 options in the tab bar, and each option is a navigation controller.  What's the difference between an info plist and a plist?

Comment: The (not an) info plist is the file containing the data used by the OS to know about the app requirements and capabilities. Another plist contains whatever you want it to.